# Sharing files stored on NTFS

Tags: ntfs

Is it possible to share files using ubuntu that are stored on an NTFS partition? I am able to see the directory on other machines, but when I click to mount the folders I get the error saying the folder is unmountable.

Answer (score 1):

I forced those looking at the NTFS files via the network to have the same permissions as me by running the following command to open the samba conf file,

```
gksu gedit /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

then added the following line to the [global] section,

```
force user = what-ever-your-user-name-is
```

then I restarted samba with,

```
sudo service smbd restart
```

More info can be seen in my thread here. http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11755517&postcount=2